# Executing a command given in string

Tags: javascript

Having the function name `'foo'` and its argument `'arg'` in strings, is there a way to execute `foo(arg)`? Do I need to use `eval`? I want to do something like `send(foo, arg)` if it were in Ruby.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use indexer notation:

```
window[name](arg);
```

Comment: I agree on window[name] but arg was also a string. window[name](window[arg]); feels as not what you always want. this[name](this[arg]); might work but not for local vars.

Comment: Assuming the function is in the global scope.